# Component to be updated when login

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a sidenav component, that if you are not login, it allows you to log in, and, it shows a menu if the user is already logged in.

The thing is that I would like to add another log in "button" in some other components, that maybe they are not direct children of that sidenav component.

As an example, app.component.html:

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-fab-container">
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav" opened="false">
        <app-profile-sidenav></app-profile-sidenav>
    </md-sidenav>

    <md-toolbar #header id="header" class="header" color="primary">
        <i (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="material-icons app-toolbar-menu clickable">menu</i>
        <span>App</span>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div class="app-content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

And, one of the component that I want to show the log in button is HomeComponent.

But, if I add that button in the HomeComponent, and I log in, in my sidenav component I can still see the template of not being authenticated.

Somehow, I have to tell the rest of the components that I am logged in.

Normally I do it with @Output(), but in this case the components are not in the same template.

Any ideas on how can I do it?

Comment: A shared service would be the way to go... https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of communication between components which are not directly related (e.g parent-child vs sibling components) is via services.

You can find more information about them here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Another possibility is to use some sort of centralised store (e.g.  ngrx/store https://github.com/ngrx/store) which can be queried or subscribed to for changes (like login, etc.)